# Conversion of raster file into a ASCII grid file using QGIS 3.4.15

Tags: qgis, raster, esri-ascii-raster

I know this question was already asked on here, but the answer from the link below did not work, at least on this QGIS, as no ASCII option was available when clicking on the files of type option.

[QGIS Export Raster to asc](https://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Export_Raster_to_asc)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you "know this question was already asked on here" what is a link to that or those question(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`.asc` is definitely there for you to choose (in Raster -> Conversion -> Translate (Convert Format)... -> Parameters tab -> Converted box -> ... button -> Save to File...). While not labeled as such, using an .asc extension produces a text file in Arc/Info ASCII grid format.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try that.

Comment: It is not at all obvious that the menu for selecting the file format opens from the right side of the  "Converted" box. The "Type" selection lets you to select the datatype (8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit etc.).

Comment: @user30184 it is the same for all QGIS tools - so how is it not obvious?

Comment: I would say that in Layer - Save as - [Format] the format selection is obvious. Also the old UI in https://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Export_Raster_to_asc is much more clear with the "Output file" selection. For my mind is is not obvious that title "Converted" means "The name of the output file".

Comment: I agree with @user30184 and also found the current listing of file extensions without accompanying file format information unnecessarily confusing, particularly as other raster save options in QGIS 3.12ish used named formats rather than extensions. (Suggested a clarifying edit.)